# Scalable architecture to download multiple zip files simultaneously

Tags: azure, architecture, distributed

We are storing files in the azure file storage system and we are giving options to users to download folders in zip files. These folders can go to 1-2 GB. And user can put 2-3 folders to download simultaneously. Of course, there could be multiple users who can be there on the system and they can put their folders on download too.

I thought of to create an API that will put each download request with a specific request Id into the Kafka queue and download service will consume the message and process to create a zip file and store the zip in temp folder in azure and return the URL back. But how to communicate to UI  from API once the zip is complete. Unfortunately, We can't do WebSockets. I thought of polling but that will become too much of polling for each user for each folder zip. Any better way we can solve this problem?

Comment: If multiple users can download the same content, then consider the usage of a cdn

Comment: No, the content will be different. Its like Google drive. Users can upload the contents to the folders and download the folders whenever they want. At the time of the download, we will zip the folder and send it for download. Now users can download multiple folders at a time and we need to queue their downloads.